# WPF Binding Object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a little problem with a ListBox and his binding.
All is good except when I call the function LstExtensionUnSelectAll() because
nothing changed, the checkbox are again checked.

I think it's a stupid thing but I don't see it.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LstExtension, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Extension}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here it's the object LstExtension :

```
public class CustomExtensions
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public CustomExtensions(string ext)
    {
        Extension = ext;
        Checked = true;
    }
}

private List<CustomExtensions> _LstExtension;
public IEnumerable<CustomExtensions> LstExtension
{
    get { return _LstExtension; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _LstExtension)
        {
            _LstExtension = value.ToList();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LstExtension");
        }
    }
}

internal void LstExtensionUnSelectAll()
{
    _LstExtension?.ForEach(c => c.Checked = false);
    NotifyPropertyChanged("LstExtension");
}
```

Comment: why didn't you add `NotifyPropertyChanged("Checked");` in `Checked` property?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the ItemsSource binding makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update your `CustomExtensions` class to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that `Checked` raises the event whenever the value changes.

```
public class CustomExtensions : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked 
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set
        {
            if (_checked == value) return;
            _checked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Checked");
        }
    }

    public CustomExtensions(string ext)
    {
        Extension = ext;
        Checked = true;
    }

    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```